# What can "Think flow" mean?

Tags: nouns, meaning-in-context

I'm investigating a Tom'n'Jerry sketch for cartoonists, containing basic graphics and tips how to draw the characters right. Unfortunately I don't have a digital version.

So the problem is with the phrase: "Think flow when connecting ear to head". I can't figure out what "flow" or "think flow" means in this context. The surrounding graphics is just general character view (full-body and head-only) and most of the other tips just describe graphical details (such as number of whiskers or toes etc.).

Does anyone get it?

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming that the intended meaning behind the quote is

> Think 'flow' when connecting the ear to the head.

It seems like an illustrative phrase, which would imply that you are supposed to have the idea of "flowing" in your head as you work on that particular part.  In other words, the ear should flow into the head (or vice versa).  It is telling you to avoid a "harsh" ear-to-head connection.

Comment: Mmm, this actually makes sense, thank you! I thought about something like "you should mind air flow in motion of ears", but it'd be totally unclear from the original statement. I've also tried to find a colloquial meaning of 'flow', but failed; so anyway, your version is the first sane one so far.